# Android Tablet Internet Access Error

Tags: android, wifi

I am working on an Android app, and it accesses the internet just fine on my phone, which uses my providers internet.

I have a tablet and it is connected to the internet via Wifi. The app crashes after about 3 seconds of trying to access the internet.
I was wondering if the code I am using has to be different when using the Wifi's internet.

I am using the HttpClient class to make a POST request.

```
public static boolean postEmailData(String emailFrom, String emailContent) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/email.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailFrom", emailFrom));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailContent", emailContent));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                return true;

            }
            else{
                return false;

            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my post and added my code.

Comment: I m talk in about the code where you called postEmailData(......) method

Comment: Why would providing you with my code help any? Surely this problem must be related to me needing to tell the app to use the wifi connection or something like that. It is just called onclick and values for the emailFrom and emailContent are sent across.

Comment: becoz i think you might be doing Network related work into your Main Thread that's why it's getting crash

Comment: Yes, but it works fine on my phone. The only issue is when the internet is connected via wifi rather than my provider.

Comment: have you added network state read permission in manifest.xml file?